# Keyboard squeeze the components

Tags: react-native

When I click on `TextInput` the components are squeezed:

[image]

How to fix it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View, TouchableHighlight, ImageBackground, TextInput, Image, Picker} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements';

class Consulta extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  ambiente:0,
  busca:''
}
}


  render(){
return(
  <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>


    <View style={{flex:5}}>
      <ImageBackground style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}} source={require('../img/bg.png')}>

        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
          <View style={{flex:1}}></View>

          <View style={{flex:10, flexDirection:'column'}}>
            <View style={{flex:1}}></View>

            <View style={{flex:2, justifyContent:'center'}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize:50, color:'#484b4c'}}>CONSULTA DE FLORES</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{flex:2, justifyContent:'center'}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'#484b4c', marginBottom:10}}>NOME OU CÓDIGO</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={{height:60, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1, backgroundColor:'white', borderRadius:10}}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({busca: text})}
              />
            </View>

            <View style={{flex:5, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
              <View>
              <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'#484b4c', marginBottom: 10}}>TIPO DE AMBIENTE</Text>
              </View>

              <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>

              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Consulta')}>
                  <Image
                    style={{flex:1.1, width: null, height: null}}
                    source={require('../img/icone/ambiente1.png')}
                  />
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>INTERNO</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Consulta')}>
                  <Image
                    style={{flex:1.1, width: null, height: null}}
                    source={require('../img/icone/ambiente2.png')}
                  />
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>EXTERNO</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Consulta')}>
                  <Image
                    style={{flex:1.1, width: null, height: null}}
                    source={require('../img/icone/ambiente3.png')}
                  />
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>INTERNO E EXTERNO</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              </View>

            </View>

            <View style={{flex:3, flexDirection:'row'}}>

              <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
              <Button
                large
                backgroundColor='#d0e25f'
                buttonStyle={{borderRadius:20}}
                textStyle={{fontSize:40, color:'#383838'}}
                iconRight={{name:'search', type:'font-awesome', size:40, color:'#383838'}}
                title='PESQUISAR'
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Resultado', {busca: this.state.busca})}
              />
              </View>

            </View>

            <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
          </View>

          <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
        </View>

      </ImageBackground >
    </View>

    <View style={{flex:1}}>

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Consulta')}>
          <Image
            style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}}
            source={require('../img/consultaOn.png')}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('FormaPagamento')}>
          <Image
            style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}}
            source={require('../img/formaOff.png')}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Organizacao')}>
          <Image
            style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}}
            source={require('../img/organizacaoOff.png')}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Horario')}>
          <Image
            style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}}
            source={require('../img/horarioOff.png')}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>

    </View>

  </View>
);
}
}

export default Consulta;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan` in the Android manifest file.

```
<manifest>
  ...

  <application>
    ...

    <activity
      ...
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) on `adjustPan`:

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing.

Comment: this solution will work only for android application but not for ios application :)

Comment: @rana_sadam he did not mention the iOS platform in his question and he used the android specific tag `react-native-android`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in an expo managed project then you have to use a property to avoid this problem. Just follow the given 3 steps:

1. Go to your app.json file
2. Paste the code under the android section: "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"
   In the android folder, your app.json should look like:
   `"android": { "adaptiveIcon": { "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png", "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF" }, "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan" },`
3. Restart your app server

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [Keyboard Aware scrollview](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) as parent wrapper in your component then the view will not squeeze and automatically scroll up when keyboard is visible on screen.

Comment: @Italo my solution will work on both ios and android the above solution to change manifest will work only for android :)